# compare two values of cell then send email

Tags: javascript, function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function myFunction() {

  const minimumLevel = [0,5,10,15,20,25,30];
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data = sheet.getRange(2,1,data.getLastRow() - 1, data.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  data.forEach((r,i) => {
      if(r[9] < minimumLevel[1]){
        console.log("true");

        // Fetch the email address
       var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("B2");
       var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();
       // Send Alert Email.
       var message = 'This is your Alert email!'; // Second column
       var subject = 'Your Google Spreadsheet Alert';
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);




      }
  })

}
```

I am trying to compare to values of cell and then if the value of that cell goes below minimum level it will send an email to someone, however I think i am stuck? please can someone help?

Comment: Which two values?  Your example is now just a copy of mine which does not compare two cells.

Comment: that's exactly where I am struggling because idk how to get the values of the cells shown below and compare them

Comment: Well if ydk the wdk and that we can't help you because have no access to your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function myFunction() {   
  const minimumLevel = [0,5,10,15,20,25,30];
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  data.forEach((r,i) => {
      if(r[9] < minimumLevel[1]){
        console.log("true");
        //send email code here
      }
  });
}
```

[image: cell to the left is the current stock level and the right is minimum level, the main condition that needs to be met is if the current stock level is less that minimum level, it will send an email to someone.. i feel like I am overthinking everything and now I cant figure it out, help would really be apprciated]

Comment: is there anyway I can loop through the minimum level array so that it can be compared to the current Stock level cell?

Comment: Probably but that seems like another question.

Comment: Hi there @jovepascual! Unfortunately I can't understand why Cooper's code isn't valid in your scenario. Could you please explain why? Also please clarify what you mean by *`the current Stock level cell`*.

Comment: @Jacques-GuzelHeron So basically I have two cells, one with the current stock level and one with the minimum stock level, my main plan is for a loop,maybe, to keep comparing two cells and if the current stock level < minimum level, send the email to someone, I have figured out the email part but I just cant figure out how to do the loop, or if loop is actually needed? I have attached a photo on the question too

Comment: You never said anything about that in your initial question.  And how long do you wish it to continue to loop?

Comment: I think you would probably be better off to trigger the function to operate with a timebased trigger to poll for the time when the value is below the minimum.

Comment: I gather that you are limiting your responses to anonymous emails.

Comment: @Cooper Hi,I apologise, I was due to reply but got distracted by the problem at hand. I want it to constantly check both columns, does that makes sense? or do you need the specific row number where the whole list end? I definitely agree on the time trigger as I want to run that every two weeks.

Comment: It makes sense that you want to do that however sooner or later the script will time out so the next best solution is to poll it with a time based trigger.

Comment: @cooper yeah that makes sense, I just dont know if I am going the right way on how to code it. because im new to this coding world and im creating sheets for our company.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241794/discussion-between-cooper-and-jove-pascual).

Comment: just create a timebased trigger and give it the functions name.  It does not require any code if you want to do it manually.  Click on the trigger menu in the editor and do it there.

Comment: After evaluating your new comments I have a better understanding of your scenario. There is one point where I still have doubts, please write back clarifying it so I can finish your anwer. I appreciate that you want to compare the `data` column against the `minimumLevel` array. What order should be followed on that comparison? Is it the first cell against the first element of the array, then the second cell against the second element, etc?

Comment: @Jacques-GuzelHeron Yes that is right, we dont necesarily need to have an array if we can just get the value of the minimum stock level and constantly compare it to the current stock level

Answer (score 0):

Based on your new comments I understand that you have two columns, one for the actual stock price and another for the desired minimum level. I also understand that your goal is to send an alert email when the stock price descends below the alert price. If my understanding is accurate, then you can reach your goals easily by making small modifications on your script.

The modified script below will first extract the data from the stock price and alert level columns. I am assuming that the stock price is on Column A and the alerts at Column B, but you can modify that easily. Then the script will run a `for` loop and if the stock price is lower than the alert level, then an email will be sent.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var stockPrice = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues()
    .flat(2);
  var minimumLevel = sheet.getRange(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues()
    .flat(2);
  var emailAddress = sheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var emailMessage = "{ ALERT MESSAGE }";
  var emailsubject = "{ EMAIL SUBJECT }";
  for (let i = 0; i < stockPrice.length; i++) {
    if (stockPrice[i] < minimumLevel[i]) {
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, emailsubject, emailMessage);
    }
  }
}
```

Please test this approach and let me know if you find any difficulties.